Can the rotation of the liquid layer of the core around the solid core stop a planet's overall spin rotation?
In some planets like Earth or Jupiter there is an external liquid or molten layer of the core which rotates around a more deeper solid core (partly due to the planet's spin itself). This dynamo effect causes the magnetic field by the induction of electric currents.
But can this rotation of the liquid layer around the solid one decrease the planet's overall spin until it stops?
I ask this because I read that it seems that there are magnetospheric currents in Jupiter that tap the rotation as an energy source. But are these currents always present? Or they can be avoided? Are these magnetospheric currents related to the currents generated by the rotating inner liquid layer around the solid core? Or this is independent from the latter?

Are you thinking that the core might speed up so the rest of the Earth has to slow down to conserve angular momentum?

Yes and also whether the rotating fluid core may decrease the planet's angular momentum (not necessarily in Earth but in other planets with magnetic fields such as Jupiter) when inducing the currents that make the magnetic field possible (perhaps they are completely unrelated but I'm not sure) @JohnRennie
